# Xamarin Forms with MVVM Navigation

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, navigation

I have added the MVVM Light libraries to my project and created a ViewModelLocator.cs file that looks like this.

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Main property.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

On my MainViewModel there are 2 commands that navigate to pages:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public INavigation _Navigation { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        _Navigation = navigation;
    }

    public RelayCommand NavigateToPage1Command
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(async() =>
            {
                await _Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
            });
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand NavigateToPage2Command
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(async() =>
            {
                await _Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
            });
        }
    }
```

}

But when the application is started it gives this message/error:

```
ActivationException: Type not found in cache: Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.
```

How and where do I need to set this? Also in the ViewModelLocator.cs file?

Comment: I guess you need to register some actual type in your `ViewModelLocator` constructor that implements the `INavigation` interface

Answer (score 0):

Best take a look at one of the examples that Laurent Bugnion made.
You'll notice that you need to have a Navigation service class defined and let your IOC know it exists.

So the registration example can be found here https://github.com/lbugnion/sample-2016-vslive-crossplatform/blob/bf734a72732409c8919a16e7b0c8e72a837e1b66/Flowers/Flowers.Forms/Flowers.Forms/App.xaml.cs#L27

The actual nav service class here https://github.com/lbugnion/sample-2016-vslive-crossplatform/blob/bf734a72732409c8919a16e7b0c8e72a837e1b66/Flowers/Flowers.Forms/Flowers.Forms/Helpers/NavigationService.cs